# Problem with using sysprep tool for running Windows on a different Hardware

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I am using sysprep tool for running Windows 7 on a different Hardware. What I do is that run sysprep on a computer, select System Audit, check the Generalize check box, select Shutdown, click OK and wait for the computer to shutdown.

When the system shuts down, I remove the hard disk from my computer and plug it into another computer having different Hardware. Then I turn ON the computer and after a series of operations (including one reboot), I eventually get to the Desktop of Windows on the changed hardware computer BUT the problem is that System Preparation Tool's start up automatically. I rebooted the computer but the System Preparation Tool start up each time.

One more thing that noted was that computer gives a message at each reboot before loading Desktop that "System is now preparing your computer for first use".

Any idea how can i get a clean Desktop after performing sysprep? or is there any step I am missing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are choosing `Enter System Audit Mode`... System audit mode is a special environment that is designed for installing programs and changing settings before an end user receives the system.

Also, by choosing the Generalize option, you are wiping the hardware settings which causes/forces Windows in to scanning for new hardware at each boot.

You only need to choose generalise when you are changing the hardware you are going to be using Windows on.

Lastly, Also, to get out of the audit mode, choose `Enter system Out-Of-Box Experience (OOBE)`. Every time you choose it, the next time you start Windows, you will get the wizard, but it should be quite quick.

So - simply choose `Enter system Out-Of-Box Experience (OOBE)`, and tick `Generalize` **but** only when you need to change computers!

[image]